# Uniform Convergence of Convolution of $f$ and Good Kernel

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, convolution

My task is to prove that if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with compact support and $\{K_\delta\}_{\delta>0}$ is a family of good kernels then $f \ast K_\delta \xrightarrow{\text{unif.}} f$ as $\delta \to 0$, where good kernels are defined to be satisfying the following:

$ (\text{i}) \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} K_\delta(x) \text{d}x = 1 $

$ (\text{ii}) \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert K_\delta(x) \vert \text{d}x \leq A $

$ (\text{iii}) \quad \int_{\vert x \vert \geq \eta} \vert K_\delta(x) \vert \text{d}x \to 0 \quad \text{ as } \delta \to 0 \text{ for every } \eta > 0 $

Here is my attempt thus far:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $E$ be the compact support of $f$, noting that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$ since $f$ is continuous everywhere. Using property (i), we may write
\begin{align*}
 \vert (f \ast K_\delta)(x) - f(x) \vert 
&= \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)K_\delta(y) \text{d}y - f(x) \right\vert \\[4pt]
&= \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( f(x-y)K_\delta(y) - f(x)K_\delta(y) \right) \text{d}y \right\vert \\[4pt]
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left\vert f(x-y) - f(x) \right\vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y
\end{align*}
We may "split" this integral into two parts in the following fashion:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left\vert f(x-y) - f(x) \right\vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y = \int_{E} \left\vert f(x-y) - f(x) \right\vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y + \int_{E^c} \left\vert f(x-y) - f(x) \right\vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y $$
Using the uniform continuity of $f$ on $E$ and property (ii) above, (I think) we then have that for some constant $c$
$$ \int_{E} \left\vert f(x-y) - f(x) \right\vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y \leq  c \varepsilon \int_{E} \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y \leq cA \varepsilon $$
This is where I get stuck. I am not sure how to bound the second integral over $E^c$. I think I need to use property (iii) by claiming that the integral over $E^c$ is somehow equivalent to integrating over $\vert y \vert \geq \eta$ but I am failing to make the connection. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ and $K_\delta$ be defined above, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f$ has finite support and is continuous everywhere, there exists some $R_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert < \varepsilon$ when $\vert x \vert \geq R_\varepsilon$. Additionally, $f$ must be uniformly continuous on the compact ball $B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$. Thus, there exists some $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon$ for every $x,y \in B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$ satisfying $\vert x - y \vert < \delta_\varepsilon$. To find a $\eta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $\vert x - y \vert < \eta_\varepsilon$, take $\eta_\varepsilon = \delta_\varepsilon$ and notice that if $x,y \in B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$ then $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon$, if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d \backslash B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$ then
$$ \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \leq \vert f(x) \vert + \vert f(y) \vert < 2 \varepsilon $$
and finally if $x \in B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^d \backslash B_{R_\varepsilon}(0)$ then we may select some $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\vert z \vert = R_\varepsilon$ to obtain the result
\begin{align*}
            \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert &\leq \vert f(x) - f(z) \vert + \vert f(y) - f(z) \vert \\
                &\leq \vert f(x) - f(z) \vert + \vert f(y) \vert + \vert f(z) \vert \\
                &< 3 \varepsilon
        \end{align*}
Using all of this, if $\vert x - y \vert < \eta_\varepsilon$ then $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon$. Additionally, we know that $\vert f(x) \vert \leq M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ since $f$ has finite support and it is uniformly continuous on such a compact set. Using property (iii) of good kernels, it is known that there exists some $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$ \int_{\vert x \vert > \eta_\varepsilon} \vert K_\delta(x) \vert \text{d}x < \frac{\varepsilon}{M} $$
We may now put this all together with property (ii) of good kernels to obtain the following:
\begin{align*}
            \vert (f \ast K_\delta)(x) - f(x) \vert 
                &=  \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f(x-y)-f(x)) K_\delta(y) \text{d}y \right\vert \\[4pt]
                &\leq \int_{\vert y \vert < \eta_\varepsilon} \vert f(x-y) - f(x) \vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y + \int_{\vert y \vert \geq \eta_\varepsilon} \vert f(x-y) - f(x) \vert \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y \\[4pt]
                &< \varepsilon \int_{\vert y \vert < \eta_\varepsilon} \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y + 2M \int_{\vert y \vert \geq \eta_\varepsilon} \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y \\[4pt]
                &< \varepsilon \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert K_\delta(y) \vert \text{d}y + 2M \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{M} \right) \\[4pt]
                &=  3 \varepsilon
        \end{align*}
Thus, we have $\vert (f \ast K_\delta)(x) - f(x) \vert < 3 \varepsilon$ for every $\delta < \delta_\varepsilon$, and hence it must be true that as $\delta \to 0$ we have $f \ast K_\delta \to f$ uniformly by definition.